# Groupe and strata in mlr3

Tags: r, validation, testing, training-data, mlr3

Hi everybody, I work actually on mlr3 and I was wondering if you could split your datas by grouping and stratify at the same time ? I saw on another topic that it was impossible...but is there no any solution ?

I mean by this question that if I have a dataset like this one :

```
structure(list(PatientID = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P6", "P6", "P6"), 
    LesionResponse = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L),.Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), F1 = c(1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 
    0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 1.25, 0.625, 0.625, 
    1.25, 1.25, 1.25), F2 = c(1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 6, 9, 0, 5, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1), F3 = c(0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 8, 4, 5, 0, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0), F3 = c(0, 9, 0, 7, 4, 0, 3, 8, 4, 5, 9, 1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 9, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

It is obvious that there are two problems :
-Class imbalance (nearly 70/30)
-PatientID have multiple observations.

In ideal situation, I must group by patientIDs and stratify by my target feature to have balanced group with no leak of informations between sets...There is no possibility in mlr3 to do this ?

Secondly, I think that, contrary to the manual of mlr3, I will create a validation set with train and test.
It is more simple for me, but, once again, I don't succeed in running my code (see below...)

```
task <- TaskClassif$new("data_cancer", data, "LesionResponse")

proportion_within_bounds <- FALSE

while (!proportion_within_bounds) {
  # Split data into train, validation and test sets by PatientID
  set.seed(123) # Set a seed for reproducibility
  
  unique_patients <- unique(task$data()$PatientID)
  train_patients <- sample(unique_patients, size = round(0.6 * length(unique_patients)))
  val_patients <- sample(setdiff(unique_patients, train_patients), size = round(0.2 * length(unique_patients)))
  test_patients <- setdiff(setdiff(unique_patients, train_patients), val_patients)
  
  train_set <- which(task$data()$PatientID %in% train_patients)
  val_set <- which(task$data()$PatientID %in% val_patients)
  test_set <- which(task$data()$PatientID %in% test_patients)
  
  train_set_df <- task$data(rows = train_set)
  val_set_df <- task$data(rows = val_set)
  test_set_df <- task$data(rows = test_set)
  
  # Calculate the proportions of "1" in the train, validation, and test sets
  train_prop_1 <- sum(train_set_df$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(train_set_df)
  val_prop_1 <- sum(val_set_df$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(val_set_df)
  test_prop_1 <- sum(test_set_df$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(test_set_df)
  
  # Check if the proportions are within the specified bounds
  if (train_prop_1 >= 0.70 && train_prop_1 <= 0.75 &&
      val_prop_1 >= 0.70 && val_prop_1 <= 0.75 &&
      test_prop_1 >= 0.70 && test_prop_1 <= 0.75) {
    proportion_within_bounds <- TRUE
  }
}
```

I'm desperate because of this...it takes infinite time to run, is there an error somewhere ??